# Are market:// redirects on Android browsers safe?

Tags: android, redirect, google-play

Are `market://` redirects on Android browsers safe? Or do some browsers on Android exist that do not follow those links to Google Play store app (e.g. maybe Samsung or other native installed browsers) ?

Comment: It doesn't matter.  Since by default Android disallows installing apps outside Google Play, even if you were redirected to an alternative market site your device would refuse to install anything.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the subject  - the question is about https://play.google.com... vs. market:// ....

Comment: I know, I posted it just as a comment.